# How can I block user's creation in feathersjs

Tags: feathersjs

I can't manage to block user's creation using FeatherJS.

I want only authentified users to create a new user.

I've tried a before hook :

```
create: [
auth.verifyToken(),
auth.hashPassword(), 
gravatar()],
```

I've tried to use :

```
all: [
auth.verifyToken(),    
auth.populateUser(),
auth.restrictToAuthenticated()
],
```

but I still can access to the signup.html page (I think that is normal because the route is not "blocked") and I still can create a valid new user (that is not normal I think).

Of course, I'm new to FeathersJS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is correct. The issue is that the user creation from the demo is using a middleware and `.create` is called from that middleware so the actual call looks like it comes from the server itself. You have two options. Either removing the middleware and moving the new user creation to the client (this is what we will change the new guides to as well) or [upgrading to feathers-authentication 1.0](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-authentication/blob/master/docs/migrating.md) and protecting the endpoint with the new `authenticate` middleware.